# Generate all subsequences of a given list with minimum possible complexity

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a list of integer elements , i want to generate all subsequences of the list,I tried this code -

```
def sequences(arr, n):
    sheet = []
    opsize = (2**n) 
    for counter in range( 1, (int)(opsize)) : 
        t = []
        for j in range(0, n) : 
            if (counter & (1<<j)):
                t.append(arr[j]) 
        sheet.append(t)
    return sheet
```

If input list - [1,2,2]

Output - [ [1], [2], [1, 2], [2], [1, 2], [2, 2], [1, 2, 2] ]

But it takes much time for any high value of n. Can anyone suggest me any other approch to minimize its complexity.

Thank you.

Comment: Look at `itertools.combinations`.

Comment: It returns a fixed length subsequences of elements from the input iterable. But i need all size of subsequences .

Comment: So just loop through `range(1, len(sequence)+1)` and call `combinations` for each length.

Comment: Here i am also worried about time complexity So please gave a approch that minimizes the time complexity.

Comment: That's as low as it gets; generating all possible subsets is inherently a `2^n` operation. Using `itertools` to generate things will at least let you do it lazily instead of keeping everything in memory, which can help with real world speed.